# detect the distance walked

Tags: android, distance, android-sensors

I'm thinking of developing an app that finds the distance of user walked. Firstly i tried to implement it via GPS location but is there any different idea with using sensors?

Basicly my app is;
The user clicks the start button and the walking starts 
The user clicks the stop button and the walking ends 
And app says you have walked bla meters.

I want to implement it without location (latitude or longtitude)

Is there any other way?

Comment: This Might Help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292617/how-to-calculate-distance-while-walking-in-android

Answer (score 5):

Maybe that can help you

- http://code.google.com/p/pedometer/
- https://github.com/bagilevi/android-pedometer

This application count steps, calculate approx. distance and speed based on user's step length .

Answer (score 0):

Your only other choice is to hook into the accelerometers and figure out what a "step" looks like. Then you'll need to prompt the user for how long their stride is, how "bouncy" they are, etc...

It won't be easy - a step will look different depending on how the phone's held: strapped to the user's waist in a belt holder, held in their hand, bouncing around in a purse, etc... A person with a light footstep won't produce as pronounced a "bump" on the sensors as someone who really slams their feet down, etc...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way would be with locations (GPS or network-based).

There's one (silly) idea I could think off:
If the device has a gyroscope, you could roll the phone over the ground, and together with the diameter of the device, you could calculate the distance ;)

But your best bet will still be usage of locations.