# How I can calculate realtime traveling distance in android?

Tags: android, gps

How I can calculate realtime traveling distance??How I can Calculate real time traveling distance by a vehicle in android programmatically. Example a car/bike travel from point A->B->C->D->C->B, than I want to calculate the total traveling distance by the car/bike on the point B by using device(Android phone) GPS.Is there any API available in android.
Please provide a direction.
your help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: you may have to use google map for such task for tracking distance.. try this<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292617/how-to-calculate-distance-while-walking-in-android>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Directions API using Waypoints will help. Below is the link to document
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

**But it has certain limits:**

Users of the free API:
2,500 directions requests per 24 hour period.
Up to 8 waypoints allowed in each request. Waypoints are not available for transit directions.
2 requests per second.
Google Maps API for Work customers:
100,000 directions requests per 24 hour period.
23 waypoints allowed in each request. Waypoints are not available for transit directions.
10 requests per second.